# method_helper in JavaScript being called on page load

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got this method_helper that I call in a JavaScript. The Javascript is supossed to be call from a button.

My problem is that the Javascript only run when I press on the button, but the Ruby method <%execute%> in it only runs on page load.

I really don't understand why it is running on page load but not when I click on the button.

The Ruby method is in application_controller.rb

Thanks in advance!

My button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="executeit()" class="btn btn-default">
```

My Javascript in the same .html:

```
function executeit() {
var selectingCommand = document.getElementById("CommandSelect");
 var selectedCommand = selectingCommand.options[selectingCommand.selectedIndex].text;
 var selectingServer = document.getElementById("serverlist");
 var selectedServer = selectingServer.options[selectingServer.selectedIndex].text;
 var username=document.getElementById("login").text;
  var password=document.getElementById("password").text;
  alert(selectedServer)
<%execute%>

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server side code like that will run at page load because that is when things are generated on the server - they are generated on the server and sent to the client. If you look at the source code client side in your browser you'll find that the output of your server side code is generated into that part of the javascript.

Executing javascript in response to a button click client side won't make anything happen server side by default.

If you want to execute server side code from client side javascript like this you may want to look at some sort of AJAX solution.